# Can we make any substance that will produce ions at low temprature

Tags: material-science, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, ions

I am talking about thermal ionization, Is to possible to make any material or is there any element that can be ionized at let say 20 degree centigrade Temperature?

I am a computer engineer and into science that much but it is just curiosity, Please correct me If I am talking nonsense.

**EDIT :**

As per I know a filament of a bulb produces photons when heat applied.
My point is can we make any material that will produce photons at less than a room temperature 
and use photoelectric effect to capture energy of photon and convert it to electricity.

Comment: Put some common salt into water and you get ions!

Comment: My point is that your question isn't really specific. How should the ions exist(Technically even an ionic solid crystal contains ions, so...)? what do you want to use them for? etc.

Comment: @udiboy I am thinking about a cooling system, like if temperature going more than 20 degree the energy will be adsorbed by irons and by some mean we will close circuit and make discharge in earth

Comment: @udiboy  I am thinking about a cooling system, like if temperature going more than 20 degree the energy will be adsorbed by irons and by some mean we will close circuit and make discharge in earth

Comment: Its a nice idea but questions like yours which talk about an unproven idea or technology are not answered here. So you should delete your question.

Comment: In general a substance that is in a neutral state will not become ionized even for high temperatures. When it reaches very high temperatures it goes into the region of the plasma, i.e. a soup of ions and electrons, still the total is neutral in charge. Ions can be produced when strong electric or magnetic or electromagnetic fields act on the substance in conjunction with conductors and specific circuits.

Comment: @anna thanks for clarification, I am making an edit to my question, can you please review it

Comment: @RupeshPatel: You don't need your edit to your own question to be reviewed. P.S. It' is not necessary for you delete the question. It will be closed soon. Or not.

Comment: The hot filament does not have ionized atoms/molecules. The photons come from  transitions from a higher excited by scattering energy levels to lower ones. The atoms remain neutral. see my answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75178/does-heat-radiation-come-from-the-nucleus-or-the-electrons/75192#75192

Answer (score 1):

You can create light from an electromagnetic field and placing florescent light bulb in that field but there still is heat from the movement of electrons needed to create that field.

[image]

Here is a link to another method that may answer your question.
http://www.rle.mit.edu/eap/documents/prl_102_223201_YbpYb_collisions.pdf