# Does heat radiation come from the nucleus or the electrons?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

Is more of the thermal radiation due to acceleration of electrons or acceleration of the nuclei? Do electrons and nuclei carry the same fractions of thermal energy in a hot body?

Answer (score 2):

In neutral atoms and molecules, heat cannot usually come from their constituents except at very high temperatures. These constituents, electrons and nucleus, are mutually bound quantum mechanically at a specific energy level and cannot radiate because they usually are at the lowest possible energy level.

Radiation from the constituents of the atoms that will contribute to heat directly may come from scatterings on each other, and if the energy is enough electrons on the outer shells may be kicked to a higher level by the impact and then decay to a lower level by electromagnetic radiation. In this sense it is the electrons that take part in the radiation, although in a center of mass system one could say the same for the nucleus-and-rest-of-the-electrons, because the energy levels are the solutions of specific potential problems.

At room temperatures most of the radiation coming from heat is due to the spill over fields of the atoms and molecules that give rise to [van der Waals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) forces . Again the kinetic energy of the atoms  in collisions , raises individual atoms to higher collective energy  in the spill over fields, and the return to ground state releases electromagnetic ratiation.

At the micro level it is quantum mechanical frameworks that are necessary for the details.

> Do electrons and nuclei carry the same fractions of thermal energy in a hot body?

The atoms and molecules as one entity carry the kinetic energy corresponding to the thermal energy. Their constituents cannot be connected with heat.

Comment: *The atoms and molecules as one entity carry the kinetic energy corresponding to the thermal energy.* This is incorrect. For example, in the hydrogen atom these two energies are related exactly by $m_eK_e=m_pK_p$; this holds as an exact operator equation, due to conservation of momentum.

Comment: *In neutral atoms and molecules, heat cannot usually come from their constituents except at very high temperatures. These constituents [...] cannot radiate because they usually are at the lowest possible energy level.* This doesn't really make much sense. It depends somewhat on what you mean by "heat." It doesn't normally refer to radiation, as implied by the 2nd sentence. Do you mean specifically black-body radiation? This only works as an explanation of why a gas at low pressure doesn't have a black-body spectrum. In condensed matter, the bb radiation comes overwhelmingly from the electrons.

Comment: *Radiation from the constituents of the atoms that will contribute to heat directly may come from scatterings on each other, and if the energy is enough electrons on the outer shells may be kicked to a higher level by the impact and then decay to a lower level by electromagnetic radiation.* This isn't going to work as an explanation of blackbody radiation, since it would then have a discrete spectrum. The reason we get a continuous spectrum from, say, a tungsten lightbulb filament is that the electrons of the different atoms all interact as one big system.

Comment: @BenCrowell It is a discrete spectrum when The Planck hypothesis hypothesizes harmonic oscillators to avoid the ultraviolet catastrophy. The continuum appears because of the huge number of these qm oscillators and the shalowness of the potentials, due to the small values of the van der Waals forces. By heat I mean the statistical heat that is connected with the degrees of freedom and enters the statisctical formulae as kT.  I think you do not really believe that quantum mechanics with its indeterminancies is the underlying structure of nature.

Comment: continued: it has no meaning to make statistical statements about the individual constituents of the atom when they are in a bound fixed energy level, as all are if they are not interacting. You yourself in your answer do not use internal to the atom degrees of freedom, claiming conservation of momentum. I claim basic quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

> Do electrons and nuclei carry the same fractions of thermal energy in a hot body?

It's nearly all in the electrons. For example, in hydrogen, the momentum of the proton and electron are equal and opposite (in the c.m. frame), so $K=p^2/2m$ is thousands of times larger for the electron. You might be tempted to imagine that there's $(3/2)kT$ worth of energy in the proton and $(3/2)kT$ in the electron, but that would violate conservation of momentum. The fundamental principle is that you get $(1/2)kT$ per degree of freedom, but because of conservation of momentum, the hydrogen atom only has 3 d.f., not 6.

> Is more of the thermal radiation due to acceleration of electrons or acceleration of the nuclei?

It's almost all from the electrons. The Larmor formula for the radiated power (averaged over a cycle) is $P=(2/3)kq^2a^2/c^3$. The accelerations of the electrons are thousands of times larger.

Comment: "The accelerations of the electons are thousands of times larger", You should qualify "free". For an electron bound  quantum mechanically in the atom there is no meaning in acceleration. It is one of the basic needs for QM, no energy is radiated by the bound electron. It is the dipole and van der waals fields  that contribute the radiation due to heat/kinetic-energy .

Comment: @annav: No, it would be pointless to apply the Larmor formula to a free electron, since there would be no acceleration and no radiation. The formula is of course classical and does not precisely predict the power radiated from an atom. Nevertheless the scaling argument that $P\propto a^2$ holds. It still makes sense to talk about averages of quantities like $a^2$ in quantum mechanics. They just aren't defined as single-valued functions of time.

Comment: I meant a free from an atom electron, sorry. Certainly to accelerate it is interacting with a field.